# How to write this Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I want to retrieve all information as well as sum of amount by the name so i use this query for that purpose.

```
select SUM(Amount)as total,RecieptNo,Name,UniqueId,Date,Amount,LateFee,Other from Amount where Name='Shaikh'
```

but this error is occured.
Column 'Amount.RecieptNo' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
 so please help me.

Comment: it's not quite clear to me what sum you want to calculate.
Total sum per name over the whole table or only the sum per recipient/Date/etc. ? In the first case: why select all the other columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Select RecieptNo, Name
    , UniqueId, Date
    , Amount
    , LateFee, Other 
    , ( Select Sum( A1.Amount )
        From Amount As A1
        Where A1.Name = A.Name ) As Total
From Amount As A
Where Name='Shaikh'
```

Another choice available in SQL Server 2005+:

```
Select RecieptNo, Name
    , UniqueId, Date
    , Amount
    , LateFee, Other 
    , Sum( Amount ) Over( Partition By Name ) As Total
From Amount As A
Where Name='Shaikh'
```

Answer (score 1):

When using aggregate SQL functions such as SUM(), you have to use a GROUP BY clause. The example below demonstrates that. This may not be the most ideal approach to tackling your query however. What I've done is added a group by clause that includes all columns that you've selected other than your SUM. For example:

```
    select RecieptNo, Total, UniqueId, Date, Amount, LateFee, Other SUM(Amount)as total  from 
Amount where Name='Shaikh' group by RecieptNo, Total, UniqueId, Date, Amount, LateFee, Other
```

Comment: you need to add other field if you want to do group by this is wrong query

Comment: @Shan Plourde: are you sure your answer is right? am in doubt.

Comment: I'm unsure if the answer will work, since there is not much information provided. The point was that the path of least resistance to correct enjoyprogramming's query is to add a group by clause, although there are many other SQL query alternatives available to choose from. All that I've added is the group by clause to the query. It may also require "Amount.ReceiptNo" as a column before the SUM(Amount).

Comment: I read enjoyprogramming's comment "Column 'Amount.RecieptNo' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause" and based my suggestion on his comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
select SUM(Amount)as total,RecieptNo,Name,UniqueId,Date,Amount,LateFee,Other from Amount
group by RecieptNo,Name,UniqueId,Date,Amount,LateFee,Other having Name='Shaikh'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by

```
select SUM(Amount)as total,Name from Amount where Name='Shaikh' group by Name
```

**If you want to add other thing in select list you require to add this field in you group by clause also otherwise it will give error**

Comment: You didn't answer the question properly. There were many other columns in the person's question. Your response was also poorly written thus difficult to understand.

Comment: @Shan Plourde - i think i have answered it correly... and written note below in bold to understand it better way

Comment: I disagree with the clarity but alas, the decision is yours.

Comment: @Shan Plourde - no need to explain if you want to do -1 its your choice